# Add CollectionType of EntityType in Symfony form

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Symfony 4 project and I would like create a CollectionType of EntityType in my form, it's possible ?

Usually I know how to do a CollectionType but this case is quite special..

My Installation entity have :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Option", mappedBy="installation", cascade={"persist"})
 *
 * @Assert\Valid()
 *
 * @var ArrayCollection|Option[]
 */
protected $options;
```

Option entity :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Option
{
   /**
    * @ORM\Id()
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned": true})
    *
    * @var integer|null
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @Assert\Type(type="string", groups={"etape_installation"})
     * @Assert\Length(max="255", groups={"etape_installation"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"etape_installation"})
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    protected $libelle;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned": true})
     *
     * @Assert\Type(type="int")
     * @Assert\Range(min="1")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     *
     * @var integer|null
     */
    protected $prix;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Installation", inversedBy="options")
     *
     * @Assert\Valid()
     *
     * @var Installation|null
     */
    protected $installation;

    public function getLibelle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->libelle;
    }

    public function setLibelle(?string $libelle): void
    {
        $this->libelle = $libelle;
    }

    public function getPrix(): ?int
    {
        return $this->prix;
    }

    public function setPrix(?int $prix): void
    {
        $this->prix = $prix;
    }

    public function getInstallation(): ?Installation
    {
        return $this->installation;
    }

    public function setInstallation(?Installation $installation): void
    {
        $this->installation = $installation;
    }

    public function __toString(): ?string
    {
        return $this->getLibelle() . ' +' . $this->getPrix() . '€';
    }
}
```

InstallationType :

```
->add('options', CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type'    => OptionType::class,
    'entry_options' => [
        'label' => 'Options supplémentaires',
    ],
    'allow_add'     => true,
    'by_reference'  => false,
    'allow_delete'  => true,
    'prototype'     => true,
])
```

[image: Option entity]

I am stuck in my OptionType..
How can I do please ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots, paste them instead

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to read symfony docs here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Comment: The documentation does not teach me anything because I already know how to create a Form Collections, but creating an EntityType FormCollections is different..